# How to add part of string dynamically based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was going through one of the values in table

[image]

If you look at last row, there is `{reason}\nIf`

Suppose their is a view or function, if you want to change the value of `{reason}`, how would I do it? using sql function?

Also what does this mean? `{reason}\nIf`

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not saying `\nIf` but `\n` and `If you...`. `\n` means a new line, so the `body` column contains:

```
{reason}
If you believe there has been a mistake, please contact support
```

To replace in Postgresql and most other DBMS', you can use the [REPLACE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-replace/) function: